# How to save breakpoints in Centura 6 Team Developer SQL/Windows

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

How can I save breakpoints in Gupta 6? When i refresh libraries after inserting some code into another .apt, my breakpoints in main program are lost. Is there any trick how to prevent from it?

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints will be saved if you save the file as TYPE binary ( i.e. save as file type = 'Normal' ) , not if saved as Text ( i.e. file type = 'TEXT' or 'INDENTED TEXT' ). This is regardless of what file extension you have .   p.s. only save as binary if you're in debug mode.  Otherwise difficult to fix if code becomes corrupt. If saved as Text - much easier to fix. [image]